# object containing information in javascript equivalent in csharp

Tags: javascript, c#, object

In javascript I use and create objects for storing information about my program like this:

```
var information = {
    page1 : {
        info : "this is some information about page 1",
        time : 1491319773386
    },
    page2 : {
        info : "this is some information about page 2",
        time : 1491319796452
    }
};
```

Is there an equivalent in csharp?
Something like this:

```
class Test {
    public static Class pages = Class {
        public static Class page1 = Class {
            public static string info = "this is page1";
            public static int date = 14487989879987;
        }
        public static Class page2 = Class {
            public static string info = "this is page2";
            public static int date = 14487989845344;
        }
    }
}
```

And the usage:

```
class Main {
    public static void main(string[] args) {
        Console.WriteLine(Test.pages.page1.info);
    }
}
```

Comment: Well you'd normally declare a class with properties instead... it's not really clear what you're asking for.

Comment: @JonSkeet Im using that inside of a class in a static property and want that information object to be value of a that parameter. can I declare a class for the value of a static property of another class?

Comment: I'm sorry, that comment made very little sense to me. I suggest you update your question with a lot more context so that it's clearly explained. (But yes, you can certainly declare types and then use them for the types of properties...)

Comment: @JonSkeet update with example. it seems crazy :) I know, but do you see a way to accomplish this kind of structure?

Comment: It seems awful like that, yes. Why would do that? What are you *really* trying to accomplish? At the moment this is really an X-Y problem...

Comment: @JonSkeet I use this method to store information about my overall program in my javascripting but in csharp I was stuck.

Comment: have a look : json2csharp.com, it convert your json to C# class

Comment: @AnupamSingh great! useful for code porting from js to cs. thanks!

Comment: So have a class which describes your information, and a *single* static variable (if you really need one) of that type. You don't want a separate class per piece of information.

Comment: @JonSkeet I have been exactly doing this till I got stock with the refactoring part of my coding. It really gets messy with too much of unrelated static properties got together. My actual intention was somehow categorizing those properties. Accepted does not means that the answer solved my problem. I simply meant that it is not possible like the js way and closing this question :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done using `static` classes nested inside each other:

```
public static class Test {
    public static class pages {
        public static class page1 {
            public static string info = "this is page1";
            public static int date = 14487989879987;
        }
        public static class page2 {
            public static string info = "this is page2";
            public static int date = 14487989845344;
        }
    }
}
```

This is similar to your example but is more neat and working.

Comment: This exactly gives me the same usage that I want!

Answer (score 0):

For this we normally use classes.
Making a class is fairly easy and simple.

```
public class Information { 
    public string[] page1 = new string[2]{"this is ...", "..."}; 
    public string[] page2 = new string[2]{"aaaa", "bbbb"}; 
}
```

You don't necessarily need to use string[] tho, in C# there are many ways to do this. I hope this is what you asked for!

Regards,
realmaster42

Comment: Can this be implemented with the `dynamic` type?